# How to append a DOMnode?

Tags: jquery

This append-procedure is working fine:

```js
document.getElementById('x').appendChild( document.importNode(node, true)  )
```

But when I try jQuery style, `$('#x').append($(node))` or `$('#x').append(node)`, not works.

---

EDIT: sorry all, I am using DOMnodes in a complex context, when using a simple short example it is working with `$('#x').append( node )`... See my Wiki-answer.

Comment: Should be `$('#x')`

Comment: oops, sorry, EDITED!

Answer (score 1):

SInce you are using document.importNode that imports a node from another document. In jquery you have to use `.contents()`

```
var ele = $(node).contents().html();
$('#x').append(ele)
```

OR

```
$('#x').append($(node).contents().html());
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul, can you demonstrate it at JSfiddle?  `contents()` not worked for me...  See examples at [my Wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44474328/287948)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose normal and [into-tag-template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) paragraph DOMnodes:

```
<div id="x"><p>...</p></div>

<p id="p1">Standard paragraph1</p>
<p id="p2">.. paragraph2, lost?</p>

<template id="t">
  <p>Templated node0!</p>
  <p>Other...</p>
</template>
```

See the complete example at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvc4mg2v/)... Tested:

```js
var t = document.getElementById('t');
var all_p = t.content.querySelectorAll("p");
var node0 = all_p[0];
var node1 = all_p[1];
if (!('content' in document.createElement('template'))) alert("NO TEMPLATE")

// append by pure Javascript:
document.getElementById('x').appendChild( document.importNode(node0, true)  )

// append by jQuery:
$('#x').append( $('#p1').clone() )  // standard behaviour as expected
$('#x').append( $('#p2') )  // but LOST IT!

$('#x').append( node0 )  // working fine, not lost!
$('#x').append( $(node0).clone() )  // working fine! (need to clone?)
// $('#x').append( node1.content )  // not work
// $('#x').append($(node1).contents().html()); // not work
$('#x').append( $(node1).html() ); // overhead to translate in to HTML
```

### Conclusions

Denoting `std_node` as "standard DOMnode" (like *paragraph1* of the example), and `tpl_node`  a node into a `<template>` tag:

- `$('#x').append( std_node )`: "side effect" deleting the node. 
  **It is not "append"** but "move node"!
- `$('#x').append( tpl_node )`: work fine.
- `$('#x').append( $(node) )`:  same "side effect" deleting the node.
- `$('#x').append( $(tpl_node) )`: work fine.
- `$('#x').append( $(node).clone() )`:  work fine.